# How to secure the data in the post form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, post, web

I want to know how to secure the data through post method , or it's secure enough ?!

I use the following on my portal :

```
 protected Control CreateCommForm(string action)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl frm = new HtmlGenericControl("form");
            frm.Attributes.Add("method", "post");
            frm.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
            frm.Attributes.Add("action", action.TrimEnd());
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            HtmlGenericControl hdn_sal_a = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
            hdn_sal_a.Attributes.Add("id", "hdn_give");
            hdn_sal_a.Attributes.Add("name", "hdn_give");
            hdn_sal_a.Attributes.Add("type", "hidden");
            hdn_sal_a.Attributes.Add("value", Session["empnum"].ToString());
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            HtmlGenericControl hdn_sal_b = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
            hdn_sal_b.Attributes.Add("id", "hdn_give_b");
            hdn_sal_b.Attributes.Add("name", "hdn_give_b");
            hdn_sal_b.Attributes.Add("type", "hidden");
            hdn_sal_b.Attributes.Add("value", Session["secret"].ToString());
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            HtmlGenericControl hdn_sal_result = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
            hdn_sal_result.Attributes.Add("id", "hdn_give_rr");
            hdn_sal_result.Attributes.Add("name", "hdn_give_rr");
            hdn_sal_result.Attributes.Add("type", "hidden");
            hdn_sal_result.Attributes.Add("value", ((99 * int.Parse(Session["secret"].ToString())) + 761).ToString());
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            HtmlGenericControl hdn_sal_h = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
            hdn_sal_h.Attributes.Add("id", "hdn_givel_h");
            hdn_sal_h.Attributes.Add("name", "hdn_give_h");
            hdn_sal_h.Attributes.Add("type", "hidden");
            hdn_sal_h.Attributes.Add("value", role_h.Hash((int.Parse(Session["secret"].ToString()) - 55).ToString(), "SHA512", null));
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            frm.Controls.Add(hdn_give);
            frm.Controls.Add(hdn_give_b);
            frm.Controls.Add(hdn_give_rr);
            frm.Controls.Add(hdn_give_h);
            body.Controls.Add(frm);
            return frm;

        }
```

Then

```
        Control frm = new Control();
        frm = CreateCommForm(process_url);
        Control crl_data = FormContent(block_type, block_id, frm);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(crl_data);
```

and i check those values in any web site opened from that portal like this:

```
var hr = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
if (hr != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(hr.AbsolutePath))
    {
        if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.Contains("master_portal"))
        {

            if (Request.Form["hdn_give"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["hdn_give"].ToString())
               && Request.Form["hdn_give_b"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["hdn_give_b"].ToString()) &&
               Request.Form["hdn_give_rr"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["hdn_give_rr"].ToString()) &&
               Request.Form["hdn_give_h"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["hdn_give_h"].ToString())
               )
            {
              //------
            }
```

---

Is this 's secure enough ,or there's some better way to do that ?

Comment: You ask about "secure enough": for any security question, the first question should be: against what specific attack? What are you trying to protect against? It isn't obvious to me what security question you are trying to ask. Those values will be freely available at the client. Is that a risk to you? How would I know?

Comment: against tampering data or injection or even get the post data then pass the checks in the sites opened from my portal .Frankly i don't know much about the security so i want to secure my data cuz it opens all the web sites in the portal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see on the code you include a connection of the user session with the post data, and that is the `Session["secret"]` and a hash of it, on this lines.

```
HtmlGenericControl hdn_sal_result = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
hdn_sal_result.Attributes.Add("id", "hdn_give_rr");
hdn_sal_result.Attributes.Add("name", "hdn_give_rr");
hdn_sal_result.Attributes.Add("type", "hidden");
hdn_sal_result.Attributes.Add("value", ((99 * int.Parse(Session["secret"].ToString())) + 761).ToString());

HtmlGenericControl hdn_sal_h = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
hdn_sal_h.Attributes.Add("id", "hdn_givel_h");
hdn_sal_h.Attributes.Add("name", "hdn_give_h");
hdn_sal_h.Attributes.Add("type", "hidden");
hdn_sal_h.Attributes.Add("value", role_h.Hash((int.Parse(Session["secret"].ToString()) - 55).ToString(), "SHA512", null));
```

Now on post back if you check that this value is the same, you can avoid one attack. Base on your code :

```
if( Request.Form["hdn_give_rr"] != null &&
    Request.Form["hdn_give_rr"].ToString()
      == ((99 * int.Parse(Session["secret"].ToString())) + 761).ToString())
{
    // User come from the same session, having the same cookie.

}
```

Comment: yeah this's what i wrote ,Is this enough to secure the data or still the user can get these data ..

another point i can't make the last check cuz the sites distributed in many servers .and the portal in a specific server.

Comment: @just_name Then add the hash of their cookie only, and not part of the session. This can avoid one attack, what you try to protect, do you have a scenario that you try to avoid ?

Answer (score 1):

you mean AntiForgery?

See the link as follow:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks